# Angular : Testing functionnal resolver?

Tags: angular, testing, karma-jasmine, resolver

I'm new to testing with Angular, but i'd like to test a newly generated component. Here are the specs :

```
describe('MyComponent', () => {
  let component: MyComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ MyComponent],
      imports: [
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        MatCardModule,
        MatListModule,
        MatIconModule,
        RouterTestingModule,
      ],
      providers: [
        MyResolver
      ],
    })
    .compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

My resolver is just a resolver that goes retrieve data from DB :

```
export const MyResolver: ResolveFn<{arg1: Arg1, user: User[]}> = (route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot):Observable<{arg1: Arg1, user: User[]}> => {
    const api: ApiService = inject(ApiService);
    
    return forkJoin({
        arg1: api.getObj('table1', route.params['id']),
        user: api.getObjList('user'),
    }).pipe(map((result: any) => {
        return {
            arg1: result.arg1,
            user: result.user,
        }
    }));
}
```

When i launch my tests, i got an error stating :

`Error: NG0204: Can't resolve all parameters for MyResolver: (?).`

I was thinking that it's because it's a functional resolver (if i try with a @Injectable one, i got another error stating it `cannot read property 'name' of undefined`)

So... Can someone help me testing this properly ?
Thanks !

I tried using the `TestBed.runInInjectionContext` but i don't seems to be using it correctly...

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `MyResolver` from `providers`. As it is just a pure function, no need to put it into `providers` section